# Is there a word for the area of the sky opposite a sunset?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word which refers to the sky directly opposite a sunset. Naïvely assumed it woulf be called nightrise, but that word does not seem to be in use.

Found a word, [noctiluca (from nox (“night”) +‎ luceō (“to shine”)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noctiluca), which I've been using as a placeholder, but if anyone other than I reads it, they'll miss the point a bit.

Comment: antipodal sky, where antipodal means: diametrically opposed to something.

Comment: I think I would call it "the darkening eastern night sky".

Comment: 'Antisolar sky' is the area of the sky opposite the sun; 'anticrepuscular sky' might suit your purposes better. See [Anti-solar (Anti-crepuscular) rays](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/anti1.htm).

Comment: Eastern works for Earth.

Comment: The *Twilight Zone*... I'll see myself out...

Comment: noctilucent refers to a specific type of high level shining cloud, so is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the ***anti-twilight*** point, but if sky is clear and you see the phenomenon of a reddening at that point, you are seeing the [***antitwilight arch***](http://www.astronoo.com/en/articles/arch-anticrepuscular.html), more poetically referred to as the [***Belt of Venus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_of_Venus).

A derivation from night+shine might be too close to *zodiacal light* for those familiar with this sort of terminology.  That's basically a diffuse band of light across the sky along the ecliptic plane.  Embedded at the brightest point of that band is *gegenschein* which is at the true antisolar point.

But you're looking at the horizon opposite a sunset, which is not the antisolar point after sunset.  The glow remaining there is at the antitwilight point.